# MVC 4 user authentication

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, authentication, user-controls, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use **user authentication** on my web project. 
When identity is verified they can see web site.
How can i do this easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **ASP.NET Forms authentication** along with the **Authorize** action filter to achieve what you desire.

Comment: 'ASP.NET Forms authentication along with the Authorize action filter' it worked, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, only the 'Safari' does not work for. Searched in the forum, everyone is having this problem. But I could not find an appropriate solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is not working? What is the problem? Can you post a new question reg. more details?